# Какие способы и приемы верстки используете вы?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Каждый знает, что верстка - это самый времязатратный, нудный, креативный и ситуативный процесс. Кто-то строит кучу костылей, чтобы прям угодить в скидываемые макеты, кто-то лепит стили прямо
в инлайн-свойство `style`, думая, что он держит и стили и верстку в одном файле, чтобы не было каши в `style.css` файле (при этом в `style.cs`s выносится только какие-то общие элементы); кто-то делает
модульную верстку как `БЭМ`, например, а кто-то просто использует `бутстрап` и ему на верстку собственно с верхней горы *(ну это пока не встретится с реальными макетами)*

Что касается меня, я использую какую-то частицу `БЭМ` методологии `-->` описываю независимые блоки и элементы внутри них и затем применяю модификаторы там для изменения цвета или размеров (`padding`,`width`).
Если нужно поправить положение элемента (`margin`,`float`,`display` и т.д.), то использую два стиля `-->` `navbar` *(как общие стили для компонента)* и `header__navbar` *(где я там отрегулирую `margin` или ширину, если она задается в процентах)*

На крайняк использую инлайн-свойство `style`, чтобы не плодить очень много блоков или элементов и их модификаторов.

Однако в таком случае у меня все равно получается каша и не совсем это удобно поддерживать, просто проходит время или же в процессе разработки я забываю, как выглядит блок по умолчанию и начинаю плодить модификаторы, чтобы
подгонять внешний вид. Соответственно после того, как я начинаю забывать, как выглядит тот или иной `блок`/`элемент` у меня просто отпадает все желание работать над проектом дальше и постоянно
все это держать в голове.

Я понимаю, что препроцессор *(например, `Sass`)* спасет ситуацию и позволит стили независимых компонентов держать в одном месте, однако как быть с тем, что я забываю, как выглядит тот или иной независимый компонент
или его элемент `-->` ладно, еще когда элементов или компонентов десятки, а когда переваливают за сотню уже такая каша начинается в голове.

Думаю верстать отдельные страницы, где у меня будут находиться все независимые компоненты и элементы `-->` например, как это делается в `UI`/`UX` дизайне *(собственно, я еще и занимаюсь дизайном)*, там создается отдельный `ArtBoard` для
компонентов и очень удобно работать с ними, даже когда их становится много.

Не могли бы вы поделиться своими мыслями, заготовками на этот счет? Ведь каждый повар имеет свои подходы и приемы.

Для верстки я использую двенадцать колонок *(в дизайне)* и эту же сетку просто беру из `bootstrap` *(только лишь сетку)*

Comment: Понимаю, что, скорее всего закроют по причине "Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.". (Даже уже вижу голоса за закрытие), но плюсану. Имхо можно было бы из вопроса сделать `верстка-faq`

Comment: Почему самый времязатратный? А если это какая-то CRM, где миллион строк JavaScript'a?

Comment: Вы находитесь в правильном направлении, старайтесь разбивать код на мелкие части, использовать `sass` и фронтенд фреймворки для создания большого структурированного проекта, `Vue`/`React` например. Чтобы не было каши в голове, пишите документацию и разбрасывайте все по компонентам.

Comment: @MoloF Спасибо большое за совет (всегда приятно слышать мнение уже опытных разработчиков) !! Не подскажете какие-то источники, где можно продвинуться в этом вопросе? Вот, я например, когда что-то ищу, всегда знаю, что там то лучше объяснили, а там нет.
Планирую изучать Vue, чтобы потом провести интеграцию с Laravel (владею им) (как говорят, Vue+Laravel -> лучшая связка)

Comment: Вместе с React можно использовать aphrodite-jss

Comment: @Rubenshtein я смотрел видео на `youtube` для минимального вхождения, а потом изучил полностью документацию, по мере своих потребностей что-то искал в поисковике и находил всегда ответы. Я подсаживался на иглу `Laravel`+`Vue`, вроде хорошо, но все же на `Nodejs` мне понравилось больше, но вам как фронтеру не особо есть разница на чем написано `API`, главное чтобы отдавало контент и ошибки.

Comment: @Voprositel Норм идея хранить стили в объектах и модульно их вставлять, только вот по БЭМу я точно также делаю или это для SPA-приложений годится и для каких-то динамических сайтов?

Comment: @MoloF На NodeJS вроде найти хостинг тяжелее (я слышал), однако я как-то интересовался NodeJS и понял, что NodeJS -> крутая штука для написания серверной части, когда речь идет о странице, которая не прекращает выполняться , то есть идет постоянная обработка серверной части в отличие от PHP, который выполняется только один раз и всего лишь является препроцессором гипертекста.

Comment: @Rubenshtein лично для себя я использовал два варианта модульности стилей проекта и в конечном итоге остановился на первом. **Первый вариант** заключается в том, чтобы создать `app.sass` файл и в нем импортировать все компоненты и остальные стили, подключаю я его в самом главном `Vue` файле и он распространяется на все остальные компоненты. **Второй вариант** заключается в том, чтобы подключать стили в определенные компоненты, если у нас кнопка, то подключаем необходимый стиль, если это `форма` или `инпут`, то другой файл `sass` и т.д.

Comment: Годится для всего, просто здесь родителю каждого модуля хешируется класс, а значит не нужно создавать длиннющие дочерние классы через два нижних подчеркивание + можно сделать стили ещё более динамическими

Comment: @MoloF Не могли бы вы показать какой-то отрывок или часть проекта (в скайпе, дискорде, личке или здесь), который разрабатывался по этому варианту? Вот один раз бы увидеть, как это все на практике реализовывается, так сразу начну применять метод у себя ツ

Comment: @Voprositel Не совсем понятно, что значит, что родителю каждого модуля хешируется класс, не могли бы вы пояснить?